# Why doesn't wstring::c_str cause a memory leak if not properly deleted

Tags: c++, multibyte, widestring, wstring

Code Segment 1:

```
wchar_t *aString() 
{
     wchar_t *str = new wchar[5];
     wcscpy(str, "asdf\0");
     return str;
}
wchar_t *value1 = aString();
```

Code Segment 2

```
wstring wstr = L"a value";
wchar_t *value = wstr.c_str();
```

If value from code segment 2 is not deleted then an memory leak does not occur. However, if value1 from code segment 1 is not deleted there is a memory leak. The internal code to wstring::c_str looks the same to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An important rule: you must use `delete` on anything that was created by `new`, and you mustn't delete anything else.

`wstr.c_str()` returns a pointer to a buffer that's managed by the `wstring` object. It will be deallocated when the string is destroyed, after which the pointer will no longer be valid. Using `delete` on this is wrong. The pointer will also be invalidated if you modify the string.

`aString()` returns a pointer to a buffer that was created using `new[]`, so you must delete it when you've finished with it (using `delete[]`, to match `new[]`). This is error-prone, which is why it is better practice to use resource-managing classes (like `string`, `wstring`, containers and smart pointers) rather than passing around raw pointers and hoping they are treated correctly.

Comment: typo: "when the string is destroyed, after which the pointer will *no longer be invalid* " -- should be *no longer be valid* or *be invalid*

Answer (score 2):

Because `c_str()` returns you a pointer to the internal representation of the `wstring`. The class keeps control of the data it contains.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the `basic_string::c_str()` [documentation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3372cxcy%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> **The returned C-style string should not
>   be** modified, as this could invalidate
>   the pointer to the string, or **deleted,
>   as the string has a limited lifetime
>   and is owned by the class string**.

Comment: Well yea... the return type of c_str is const char*/wchar_t*

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that a wstring is not a wchar_t, but instead a class that has an operator to return a wchar_t *, so in the destructor of wstring, it likely frees its own copy of the wchar_t * it returns.

Comment: It's not an operator, it's an explicit function call `cstr()`.  This is one of the most heavily used classes in the standard, I'm really quite shocked that the highest voted answer is guessing about it.

Comment: I have worked for a long time at a company that has their own string classes from before wide adoption of STL (a bit of a 'not written here' mentality), so for years those are what I have used.